# Copy / Back up all images on Android phone to SD Card with folders

Tags: raspbian, ssh, image, backup, rsync

I am running a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B as a VPN Gateway with `OpenVPN`. On my Samsung S8, I have the app `OpenVPN for Android` installed and the VPN tunnel to my home network works like a charm.

What I want to achieve now is the following: As my Raspberry Pi has an SD card with huge storage, I want to copy / backup all my images I have on my Android phone to this SD card with the folders being named just like they are on my Android phone.

I saw that `rsync` can be used maybe. However, I wasn't able to find a proper tutorial for my usecase: I don't want the files on the SD card in the Raspberry to be deleted - never, even when they are deleted on the phone - but only the newer images to be uploaded.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: `rsync` only deletes if you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it and thank you goldilocks for your answer.

### Android Side

I installed the app `Rsync Wrapper` on my Samsung and configured it with the following parameters:

Source: `/storage/WXYZC-ABCD/DCIM/Camera/`

Destination: `username@192.168.2.4:~/userS8/`

Option: `-r --ignore-existing --progress -e "ssh -l username -i /data/user/0/net.letscorp.rsyncwrapper/files/00a00b00-1111-22c3-44de-5fgg6hi7j888.key -y"`

The option tag will be created more or less automatically by `Rsync Wrapper` when you create the SSH key pair.

### Raspberry Side

`sudo apt-get install rsync`

Create the directory `.ssh` and the file `authorized_keys` if not already there in `~` (`home`) `username:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Put the public key from the app `Rsync Wrapper` into the file `authorized_keys` and test it with a dry run on `Rsync Wrapper`.